# vlookup a value and return if it is after a certain date

Tags: google-sheets, formula

Hello I Have a sheet with a list of names, medications, statuses and correlating dates on a spreadsheet. On a separate spreadsheet I would like to be able to type in a date and status (ex. "Pending", "active") and have the correlating patient names come up.
If i Type in 5/6/21 and then "active" I would like the formula to search the master-sheet and return names of patients whos status is "Active" after the Date 5/6/21.

Comment: The `QUERY` function should be able to do this easily. Can you share a sample sheet so I can see how I can write that for you? Obviously don't use actual names in the sample.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1cpDqaxMxiVO3quC2ttYy15YrmvV2D07lj9_zleeCpzo/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1afD3cQpKiyxhDz-ORwr29batQnMSXsTINWISEilMMbE/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: The Example data is whee i would like the data pulled from. on the example sheet i would like to be able o put in date and status and the rest populates

Answer (score 0):

I can't open your second sheet, but based on the first one, I've added a date input in cell F2.

Sheets `QUERY` is a powerful function that is similar to SQL. It can be used to display data from a dataset based on certain parameters (like your date search, and status = active).

In the example, the following `QUERY` formula goes in cell H1, but you can move it to a different tab if needed, obviously referencing `'DATA'!A:E` etc.

`=if(isblank(F2),,iferror(query(A:E,"where D > date '"&text(F2,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' and lower(E) contains 'active' order by D,A",1),"No result"))`

**functions**

`isblank` - if cell F2 is blank (the date search), then nothing.

`iferror` - if the `query` doesn't return any values, just output the wording 'No result'.

`query` function - as per the parameters below.

The range of your data is cells `A:E`.

The `where` clause basically says that the value in col `D` needs to be greater than the date within the single quotes `''`, which contains `"&text(F2,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"`, which is the value of cell `F2`, formatted as `text` in the structure `yyy-mmm-dd`.

Placing `"&<Sheets function>&"` within the single quotes `''` allows you to put another Sheets function in the query syntax, in this example the `text` function that formats the input of cell F2 as a date `yyyy-mm-dd`.

The where clause also includes an `and` where the lowercase of column E, `lower(E)` contains the word `'active'`.

The results are `ordered` by column D then column A.

The `,1` at the end of the query tells it to treat the first row of data as headings. If it was data and not a heading, then it would be `,0`.

Let me know if you need it implementing on your actual sheet.

[image]